# Brush Opacity changes after Making Mask in Illustartor

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, gradient, mask, brush

Following [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/3832011-GRAIN-and-NOISE-TEXTURE-Adobe-Illustrator-Tutorial) great tutorial by Gigantic about creating "grainy gradient", I face a problem after masking.

I have two layers: 1st one is the object itself which is a [Rectangle] and another Group including paths.
As mentioned in the video, I select the group, then in the "Transparency Panel" I create a mask and then copy the object in the black box. Everything works well except the opacity of brush paths. I'm not sure if it's related to the brush or is a bug - maybe.
I don't have this problem with general brushes.

Ticking "Invert Mask" helps a little, but the opacity isn't still 100%.

I'm using Spoon Graphics Stipple Shading brushes from the free bundle.

Comment: By the way you would get a lighter scene if you used a clipping mask instead. And also you will have less elements in your scene if you later fill the clipping mask yoth your bg color

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Didn't watch the video)</sub>

For **Opacity Masks** (which is what you've described) to mask everything entirely you need to ensure the black you are using is **100C/100M/100Y/100K** or **0R/0G/0B** -- all channels need to be solid **on the mask**. Basically, use the "Registration" swatch.

If you simply use 100% K in areas on the mask, they will be a dark grey and not fully mask everything.